# Get url links of search results from GEO DataSets using pagination

Tags: php, python, pagination, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to get all the links of each article from this page of search results:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=lung+cancer

But I have problem getting the url of next page. From `<div class="pagination">`, it says:

```
<a name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page" title="Next page of results" class="active page_link next" href="#" sid="3" page="2" accesskey="k" id="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page">Next &gt;</a>
```

Therefore I used python urllib to retrieve the url of next page in order to use BeautifulSoup to get its contents:

```
param2=urllib.urlencode({'sid':3,'page':2,'accesskey':'k','id':'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Gds.Gds_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page'})

f2=urllib.urlopen('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=lung+cancer',param2)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(f2.read(), 'html.parser')
```

Now the problem is, even if I change page number from 1 to 10, I always get the contents of page 1. Can anyone please tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should send a lot of data (by making POST request) in order to obtain next page. Use Developer tools in any browser to check which data you required to send.

[image]

(not all data is shown)

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, do you mean I have to try several combinations to guess the correct url?

Comment: I mean that you don't need to construct any 'magic' url to retrieve your data, but it seems you have to explore a huge amount of data to send in `param2`. In my opinion it will be much easy to use Selenium or similar tool.